# How to pass in UserData as a parameter in CloudFormation

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that creates an EC2 instance with an UserData script that should be assigned with the `LaunchUserData` parameter:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Create an AMI from an EC2 instance.
Parameters:
  LaunchUserData:
    Description: Base64-encoded user data to launch EC2 instances.
    Type: String
  GitSSHKey:
    Description: Git SSH key
      Type: String
Resources:
  LaunchEc2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      UserData: ...
```

`LaunchUserData` is a bash script that will reference some of the stack's parameters and resources:

```
#!/bin/bash


GIT_SSH_KEY=${GitSshKey};

echo "$GIT_SSH_KEY" | base64 -d > $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa;

echo ${AWS:Region};
```

I want to create the stack via CLI as follows:

```
GIT_SSH_KEY="somesshkey"
LAUNCH_USERDATA=$(jq -Rs . < $PWD/templates/launch)
STACK_ID=$(aws cloudformation create-stack \
--stack-name test \
--template-body file://$CLOUD_FORMATION_FILE \
--parameters \
    ParameterKey=GitSSHKey,ParameterValue="$GIT_SSH_KEY" \
    ParameterKey=LaunchUserData,ParameterValue="$LAUNCH_USERDATA" \
--output text \
--query 'StackId');
```

The `LaunchUserData` script, once interpreted, must reference and substitute its `${}` variables with parameters and resources of the current stack, hence, when the user-data script is retrieved (and executed) within the EC2 instance, it should look like this:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data

#!/bin/bash


GIT_SSH_KEY=somesshkey;

echo "$GIT_SSH_KEY" | base64 -d > $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa;
echo us-east-1;
```

Note how the script might also reference other CloudFormation resources.

How can I correctly pass `LaunchUserData` parameter to UserData without hard-coding it into the template?

Comment: It isn't in: in this example I'm using an Amazon-proprietary AMI

Comment: Oh I see, you're looking to pass in the userdata as a variable. Bit weird, why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: @Paolo I want to keep my templates clean and not write any inline code. What other approaches do you suggest as optimal?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is use a single template for completely different EC2 instances, right? In that case, I'd advise having separate templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Create an AMI from an EC2 instance.
Parameters:
  LaunchUserData:
    Description: Base64-encoded user data to launch EC2 instances.
    Type: String
  GitSSHKey:
    Description: Git SSH key
      Type: String
Resources:
  LaunchEc2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          export GitSshKey="${GitSSHKey}"
          echo "${LaunchUserData}" | base64 -d | bash
```

so decode the parameter and pipe it to bash.

Do note however that `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` will always return whatever is present in the template itself.

Comment: In your example the output of `echo "${LaunchUserData}" | bash64 -d` would container literal interpolated variables that did not go through `Fn::Sub`

Comment: @Constantin yep, I had forgotten the `export` command. Try now